# read preference configuration for transactions

Tags: mongodb, transactions

I am reading the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) for multi-document transactions in MongoDB, but I cannot really understand the point of setting read preference in a transaction. [This](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions-and-read-preference) is what I mean:

> Operations in a transaction use the transaction-level read preference.
>
> Using the drivers, you can set the transaction-level read preference
> at the transaction start:
>
> - If the transaction-level read preference is unset, the transaction
>   uses the session-level read preference.
> - If transaction-level and the
>   session-level read preference are unset, the transaction uses the
>   client-level read preference. By default, the client-level read
>   preference is `primary`.
>
> Multi-document transactions that contain read
> operations must use read preference `primary`. All operations in a given
> transaction must route to the same member.

Basically, there are 3 levels from where MongoDB can retrieve the read-preference; if it is not specified in any of these, by default is `primary`.

### Question

why should I need to specify the read-preference, if in a multi-document transaction only `primary` is allowed? In a transaction that does not contain read operations I do not even care to set it because of no use, am I wrong? It just feels overcomplicated to me.

Comment: To make the interface a little bit more future proof? Current implementation requires to read transaction writes from the same member but it may change in the future. As the quoted doc says, if you don't read within the transaction you can ignore the requirement.

Comment: @AlexBlex that makes sense, thank you.